# Querying custom database(Mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a search bar to query an api endpoint that searches my database for specific titles. I have tested my route on Postman and it works correctly however when I try to hit my api on my frontend it returns nothing. I have tried logging the response I get from my axios call however when I do so the page fails to compile and my response is declared as not defined(no-undef). Here are my files:

Frontend file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import NavigationBar from "../Components/HomeNav";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const Search = () => {
  const [queryTitle, setQueryTitle] = useState({});
  const [queriedPosts, setQueriedPosts] = useState(null);

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setQueryTitle({ title: event.target.value });
    axios
      .get("/api/posts/search", queryTitle)
      .then((response) => setQueriedPosts(response.data), console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <NavigationBar />
      {queriedPosts
        ? queriedPosts.map((post) => {
            return (
              <>
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
              </>
            );
          })
        : ""}
      <Button onClick={() => console.log("title", queryTitle)}>rest</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => console.log("posts", queriedPosts)}>rest</Button>
      <h1>Search</h1>
      <input
        id="title"
        name="title"
        type="text"
        name="recipes"
        onChange={handleSearch}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Route file

```
const router = require("express").Router(),
jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let User = require("../db/models/User"),
Post = require('../db/models/Post');

router.post("/api/users", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  let user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (user) {
    throw new Error("Use a different email!");
  }
  try {
    const newUser = new User({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });

    const token = await newUser.generateAuthToken();
    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "Strict",
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? false : true,
    });

    res.status(201).json("User added");
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.toString() });
  }
});

router.post("/api/users/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {

    const user = await User.findByCredentials(email, password);
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken();

    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "strict",
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? false : true,
    });
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.toString() });
  }
});

router.get("/api/posts/search", async (req, res) => {
  const { title } = req.body;
  try {
    const recipeTitle = await Post.find();
    const recipeQuery = recipeTitle.filter(post => {
      let recipeName = post.title;
      return recipeName.includes(title) || recipeName.toLowerCase().includes(title);
    })
    res.json(recipeQuery);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({error: error.toString()})
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I am not exactly sure what is going on as I am expecting for my response to at the very least return an empty array or am I wrong to assume that? Also after entering a query string queriedPosts returns as an empty array and queryTitle returns as an Object {title: 'string'}.

After fiddling with my backend route file I have discovered that when I comment out my filter method and return recipeTitle my web page will display all the titles of the all the posts in my database however this does not explain why Postman returns a correctly filtered response.

Comment: Does your axios get request have a baseURL set? If you're server is running locally the URL should be something like ```http://localhost:3000/api/users```. Also can you check the dev tools to see more request info.

Comment: When I log documents.baseURI I get localhost:3000/search which is the local url I am on. Also I have tried playing with the route and discovered that my filter method could be a possible culprit. When I comment it out and return Post.find() I get all the posts in my database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After much help I found a way to correctly populate my webpage with the queried string a user would pass through.

Frontend file

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post("/search/api/posts/", queryTitle)
      .then((res) => {
        setQueriedPosts(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [queryTitle]);

  const handleSearch = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let recipeTitle = event.target.value;
    setQueryTitle({ title: recipeTitle });
  };
```

These are the only changes I made to the frontend file. My input element runs handleSearch which updates my queryTitle state. Instead of a get request, I send a post request to my backend. The useEffect is used to properly update and display the state change of the posts we wish to query. In the dependency array of the useEffect, I put queryTitle to make my component re-render.

Backend file

```
router.post("/search/api/posts/", async (req, res) => {
  const  title  = req.body.title;
  const regex = /title/g
  try {
    const recipeTitle = await Post.find({title: {$regex: title, $options: '<gi>'}});
    res.json(recipeTitle);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({error: error.toString()})
  }
})
```

In my backend file I changed my get request to a post request and removed my filter method and used find(). When passed an object with the property and value you wish to query in your database find() will filter out any occurrences that do not match via the regex expression. More about this concept on the MongoDB docs. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is with this line: `.then((response) => setQueriedPosts(response.data), console.log(response))`. I think you want to log the `response` on success, however, you somehow ended up trying to log it when the promise is rejected.

The `.then()` method takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the promise.

```js
.then(
  // first callback, function is called if the promise is fulfilled
  (response) => setQueriedPosts(response.data), 
  // second callback, "function" is called if the promise is rejected
  // response is undefined
  console.log(response)
)
```

If you try to log the response in the first callback, you won't receive an undefined variable error:

```js
.then((response) => {
  setQueriedPosts(response.data);
  console.log(response);
})
```

Another issue is that when you try to fetch the search results you pass the previous `title` state and not the current one. Don't forget that `useState` is asynchronous. You can't update the state on one line and assume it's already changed on the next one. So save the input value and use that in your request instead.

```js
const handleSearch = (event) => {
  let title = event.target.value;
  setQueryTitle({ title });
  axios
    .get('/api/posts/search', title)
    .then((response) => {
      setQueriedPosts(response.data);
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
};
```

And as [Kyle mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282676/quering-custom-databasemongodb#comment115414340_65282676), make sure that the API URL is correct.

On the backend your current filter wouldn't find `'Pumpkin Muffin'` if the user types `'muFfin'` in the search field. You should update it, just convert both the title and the search term to lowercase:

```js
const recipeQuery = recipeTitle.filter((post) => {
  return post.title.toLowerCase().includes(title.toLowerCase());
});
```

Comment: This helped in the .then, but for the latter my page errors out because I need to send an object with a key value pair of title and a string to the backend. I changed your fix but now for some reason my string is undefined and it does't work on postman either

Comment: `setQueryTitle({ title });` is just the shorthand form of `setQueryTitle({ title: title });`, so it is a key-value pair. Not sure which string is undefined though. On the front end or the back end? Could you clarify that?